# Replace if else with ternary not working

Tags: java, ternary

I am trying to replace this piece of code with ternary expressions :

```
if (m_dataSource instanceof URL) {
        m_audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream((URL) m_dataSource);
        m_audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat((URL) m_dataSource);

    } else if (m_dataSource instanceof File) {
        m_audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream((File) m_dataSource);
        m_audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat((File) m_dataSource);

    } else if (m_dataSource instanceof InputStream) {
        m_audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream((InputStream) m_dataSource);
        m_audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat((InputStream) m_dataSource);
    }
```

what i am trying:

```
  m_audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                         m_dataSource instanceof URL?(URL)m_dataSource
                           :m_dataSource instanceof File?(File) m_dataSource
                             :m_dataSource instanceof InputStream ?(InputStream) m_dataSource
                               :(something other));
```

but i am getting this error:

**The method getAudioInputStream(InputStream) in the type AudioSystem is not applicable for the arguments (((m_dataSource instanceof URL) ? (URL) m_dataSource : ((m_dataSource instanceof File) ? (File) m_dataSource : ((m_dataSource instanceof InputStream) ? (InputStream) m_dataSource : null))))**

Why it choose InputStream by default?

Edit :
**m_dataSource is Object.**

Comment: Am I missing something -- you check that m_dataSource is a URL, then you cast it to be a URL, which it already is? This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be parsing the ternary conditionals.

Comment: @Engineer Dollery i am trying to replace the if else i have mentioned above if the first is false go to other if true get this... and so on

Comment: Yeah, I can see that, I'm wondering why -- you don't need any of that code, except the calls to the methods, without any of the casting or type checking.

Comment: @howTo I think he meant why are you casting it to, say, URL inside the condition if you are checking if it is a URL

Comment: unless you have other code in the conditionals, `m_audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(m_dataSource);` should just work

Comment: @Enginner Dollery i am trying to make the code smaller ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ternary operator can only return the same type of object.  In this case your method is expecting an `InputStream`, so all actual possibles of the ternary must be a InputStream.  I am guessing that `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()` has overridden methods for accepting a URL, File, and InputStream.

Comment: Yes it has but i want to make the code smaller that's all.I din't knew that ternary operator can only return the same type of object... thanks!